# Variable value is not increased

Tags: vba, excel

My variable value (Excel-VBA) is not getting increased. Please help me. Following are the syntax:

```
Do

    Sheets("PF Data - Monthly").Select

    PF_WAGE = PF_WAGE + Range("D" & row_no).Value
    PF_EMP = PF_EMP + Range("E" & row_no).Value
    PF_367 = PF_367 + Range("F" & row_no).Value
    PF_833 = PF_833 + Range("G" & row_no).Value

    row_no = row_no + 1

Loop Until Range("A" & row_no).Value = AC_NO
```

Comment: have you initialized your `row_no` variable?

Comment: (1) Avoid using `.Select` this is a bad practice. Instead specify a worksheet for your ranges like `Set wsData = Worksheets("PF Data - Monthly")` and then use `wsData.Range(…)` (2) what is the value of `row_no` and is there a value in this row? How are the variables e.g `PF_WAGE` declared (what type are they). Please show some more of the code.

Comment: it would really help a lot if you mentioned which variable you are talking about ... i am just not able to read your mind today for some reason

Answer (score 1):

A simple `With` can help you make all the difference.

Then, inside the `With` you need to qualify all `Range` objects, by adding a `.`. i.e. `.Range("D" & row_no).Value`

**Code**

```
row_no=1

With Sheets("PF Data - Monthly")
    Do
        PF_WAGE = PF_WAGE + .Range("D" & row_no).Value
        PF_EMP = PF_EMP + .Range("E" & row_no).Value
        PF_367 = PF_367 + .Range("F" & row_no).Value
        PF_833 = PF_833 + .Range("G" & row_no).Value

        row_no = row_no + 1
    Loop Until .Range("A" & row_no).Value = AC_NO
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
dim row_no as long  
dim ws as worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("PF Data - Monthly")

row_no = 1 ' initialize it
Do

    PF_WAGE = PF_WAGE + ws.Range("D" & row_no).Value
    PF_EMP = PF_EMP + ws.Range("E" & row_no).Value
    PF_367 = PF_367 + ws.Range("F" & row_no).Value
    PF_833 = PF_833 + ws.Range("G" & row_no).Value

    row_no = row_no + 1

Loop Until ws.Range("A" & row_no).Value = AC_NO
```

Comment: If it was `row_no = 0` (not initialized) then it would throw a runtime error on `Range("D" & row_no).Value`. You can easily test this with `Debug.Print Range("D" & 0).Value`. So this cannot be the issue, and therefore not the solution.

Comment: @Peh I totally understand what you are saying but given the amount of sample code what can you make up... say you are true but this code snippet is inside `If error go to next` statement ....?

Comment: @Peh now what is the difference between my code and Sahi Rado's code... Don't get me wrong but my code was just systematic. which I felt was missing in the question, if this also doesn't works for him then I think we can look forward for other things which is exactly your point... :)

Comment: Don't take it personally, but that happens when you post code only answers without any explanation. (a) learning effect of such answers are very low. (b) I assumed that you think the issue is in not initializing  `row_no` (because of that code comment). But I think that cannot be the issue because if it wasn't initialized already then it must be `0` or `""` and this would result in a runtime error (which wasn't reported by the OP). (c) sometimes some explaining text what was done and why makes a useless answer a good answer. And avoids confusing and assumptions.

Answer (score -1):

You have to ad this line to your code: row_no = 1 because row_no by default has the value of zero.

row_no = 1

Do

```
Sheets("PF Data - Monthly").Select



PF_WAGE = PF_WAGE + Range("D" & row_no).Value
PF_EMP = PF_EMP + Range("E" & row_no).Value
PF_367 = PF_367 + Range("F" & row_no).Value
PF_833 = PF_833 + Range("G" & row_no).Value

row_no = row_no + 1
```

Loop Until Range("A" & row_no).Value = AC_NO

End Sub

Comment: That's wrong. If it was `row_no = 0` then it would throw a runtime error on `Range("D" & row_no).Value`. You can easily test this with `Debug.Print Range("D" & 0).Value`. So this cannot be the issue, and therefore not the solution.

Comment: row_no, must be an integer or a long because the range("D" & row_no).value must be something like  range("D2") .There is no row in excel that begins from 0, probably you have confused with VB.if you run the code from VBA editor you take the error 1004.

Comment: Yes there is no row 0, and that is why you would get an error message if the variable `row_no` was `0`. But the OP didn't say that there are error messages, he said it doesn't increase, so we can assume that the code runs without errors. And therefore that can not be the issue here. So I confused nothing.

Comment: if you run OPs code when you set row_no=1 his variable increase normally.

Comment: When you run a macro, all the variables are initialized to a value. A numeric variable is initialized to zero, a variable length string is initialized to a zero-length string (""), and a fixed length string is filled with the ASCII code 0. Variant variables are initialized to Empty. An Empty variable is represented by a zero in a numeric context and a zero-length string ("") in a string context.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/843144/how-to-use-variables-in-excel-sub-procedures-in-visual-basic-for-appli.

Comment: You don't understand what I mean I think. If you assume that it was not initialized then `row_no` is `0` or if it is a string then `""`. But then we will get an error message. But he didn't tell something about an error message. So if there is no error our assumption that  `row_no = 0` or ` `row_no = ""` is wrong. Therefore that cannot be the issue.

Comment: ok then please answer my question: why when row_no initialized to zero the variable increased without issue?Before you score negatively an answer please run the code first!!

Comment: Insert in the first 10 cells in column A the value AC_NO and run the following sub:

Public Sub test()



Do

    Sheets("PF Data - Monthly").Select
    
    

    PF_WAGE = PF_WAGE + Range("D" & row_no).Value
    PF_EMP = PF_EMP + Range("E" & row_no).Value
    PF_367 = PF_367 + Range("F" & row_no).Value
    PF_833 = PF_833 + Range("G" & row_no).Value

    row_no = row_no + 1
    
    MsgBox row_no
    


Loop Until Range("A" & row_no).Value = AC_NO
End Sub

Comment: "*why when row_no initialized to zero the variable increased without issue?*" That's, just not true, I did test this. If I run your code initialized with `row_no = 0` or without initialization of `row_no` then I get runtime error 1004 on `Range("D" & row_no)` both times.

Comment: row_no=1 , i wrote zero by mistake

Comment: Insert in the first 10 cells in column A the value AC_NO and run the following sub

Public Sub test()

row_no =1


Do

    Sheets("PF Data - Monthly").Select
    
    

    PF_WAGE = PF_WAGE + Range("D" & row_no).Value
    PF_EMP = PF_EMP + Range("E" & row_no).Value
    PF_367 = PF_367 + Range("F" & row_no).Value
    PF_833 = PF_833 + Range("G" & row_no).Value

    row_no = row_no + 1
    
    MsgBox row_no
    


Loop Until Range("A" & row_no).Value = AC_NO
End Sub